# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli)

Tags: java, spring, javafx, maven

Возникла проблема при сборке javaFX проекта java 1.8, на spring. Maven выбрасывает эксепшн -

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project ChessmanSales: The parameters 'executable' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Создал обычный проект, там все ок. Тут не пахает. В чем причина?
Вот pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.chessman.mavenproject2.MainApp</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
        <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.23.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Предполагаю, что Ваш Main.java файл ошибочно расположен здесь `src/test/java`. А maven ищет в `src/main/java`.

Comment: @invzbl3 Путь: mavenproject2\src\main\java\com\chessman\mavenproject2\MainApp

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить [Exec Maven Plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/exec-maven-plugin) в зависимости:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/exec-maven-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

И в `build` секцию:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>...</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
     ...
   </plugins>
</build>
```

*Указав свой путь в `<mainClass>...</mainClass>` соответственно.*

Также проверьте подключение [javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin) в док-е.

[Кроме того, такая проблема может возникать из-за несоответствия версий](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20293087/8370915)

Comment: Увы, но без успешно, не помогло...

Comment: Ошибка та, что и была? Проект не собирается как в IDE, так и просто с помощью командной строки?

Comment: Если работаете в среде NetBeans, то попробуйте еще такой [вариант](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21552906/8370915).

Comment: Я работаю в среде NetBeans, в командной строке еще не пробовал. Как попробую отпишусь.